# What is the way to know that the endpoint is down if there is an L4 / L7 balancer?

Tags: api, fuzzing

I'm writing an API-fuzzer and I want to detect if a sequence cause falling down of an endpoint of some service. Of course I can get 500 response code, but it's may be called from code of an endpoint. And there are any exact way to find out if a server is down?

I don’t know in advance what kind of balancing is on the service side. So I will be glad to know a universal solution, or some particular one.

Comment: A simple (but not bulletproof) approach is to try each request twice and see if you get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is really possible nowadays, when you make a TCP connection to a server, you may thing thats the endpoint, probably that TCP connection is balance to other systems that depending on the policy of the load balancer could be the same physical host or not. This policies sometimes are dynamic and may vary depending on the load, so your HTTP Request could go to different endpoints depending on how is design the backends.